# how to create JPAQueryFactory correctly with QueryDsl

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

I heard about `EntityManager` is **not thread-safe**, so we use `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Autowired`.

However, I found about two ways to create JPAQueryFactory on the Internet.

1. define a bean like this

```
@Configuration
public class JPAQueryFactoryConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory(@Autowired EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

2. @PersistenceContext on EntityManager ,new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager) every time

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void test(){
        JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
        xxxxxxxxxxxx
    }
}
```

I'm counfused. But, I think the first way is not correct according to the difference between @PersistenceContext and @Autowired

Comment: It is the correct way. The `EntityManager` in this case is a proxy which at runtime will resolve to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

As [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jpa-querydsl-taking-best-from-both-wor) shows, you need to use both the entity manager and `JPAQueryFactory` as follows:

Extend `SimpleJpaRepository` and implement `BaseRepository`

- `BaseRepository` is an interface that extends `JpaRepository`

> ```
> public abstract class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID> 
>         extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> 
>         implements BaseRepository<T, ID> {   
>      
>     EntityManager em;
>     JPAQueryFactory queryFactory;
>         
>     public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
>         super(domainClass, em);
>         this.em = em;
>         this.queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
>     }
> }
> ```

and create a class that extends your `BaseRepositoryImpl` to use `JPAQueryFactory` in it.

Answer (score -1):

i am just  biginer in EJB ,
type of JPAQueryFactory  is Provider
is not EntityManager , just Cast

```
JPAQueryFactory query = new JPAQueryFactory((Provider<EntityManager>) em);
```

or use the declaration  of  JPAQueryFactory

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = 
  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.baeldung.querydsl.intro");
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
JPAQueryFactory queryFactory = new JPAQueryFactory(em);
```